# How to addres Uk Visa refusal for financial reasons

Tags: uk, visa-refusals, proof-provenance-of-funds

How do I address a refusal based on unexplained large deposits in account that do not have origin and the fact that my bank statements do not correspond to stated level of income and expenditure.
And the fact that the planned budget is too high compared to my monthly income.
Even though it was stated clearly that I have quarterly payments and additional return on investment annually plus savings for over 10 years I have worked.

Comment: DId you actually show any *evidence* that these large deposits correspond to your quarterly payments, etc?

Comment: If you’ve not read this https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/92121/uk-visa-refusal-on-v-4-2-a-c-and-sometimes-e already, do so before you re-apply